# Make Haskell type system understand that fundeps carries over a composite (tuple-like) type

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies, type-level-computation

I have the following code, which I use to convert a HList-of-touples (or more like, tree-of -touples) into the same shape, but instead of a tuple, just keeping the second element.

The problem is, this needs `UndecidableInstances` (see the error message in comment). Is it possible to make the type system aware that indeed, `a :. c` determines `b :. d` so the error (and the need for UndecidableInstances) to go away?

```
class TupSnd a b | a -> b where                                                                                                
  tupSnd :: a -> b                    
                                                                                                                               
instance TupSnd PGTup (Only Action) where                                                                                      
    tupSnd a = Only (snd a)                                 
                                                               
-- This needs UndecidableInstances allegedly, but probably there's some type-level trick to make it work?
--                                                                                                                             
-- Error:                    
--                                                    
--   Reason: lhs type ‘a :. c’ does not determine rhs type ‘b :. d’
--                                                                                                                             
-- Which sounds like it shouldn't be the case logically.                                                                       
instance (TupSnd a b, TupSnd c d) => TupSnd (a :. c) (b :. d) where       
    tupSnd (a :. c) = tupSnd a :. tupSnd c
```

For context, `:.` is the glorified tuple constructor helper from `postgresql-simple`, and I also have

```
type PGTup = (Identifier, Action)
type PGTup2 = PGTup :. PGTup   
type PGTup2_2 = PGTup2 :. PGTup2                         
type PGTup3 = PGTup :. PGTup2
type PGTup4 = PGTup :. PGTup3
```

Comment: I think this does not fall within the [rules for termination](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/instances.html#instance-termination-rules). Specifically, look at the last `Mul` example, which looks terminating, but is not. Probably, you need to turn on `UndecidableInstances` -- the extension is harmless IMO. I'd also be tempted to move to type families instead of fundeps.

Comment: @chi Indeed, with UndecidableInstances it works as expected. Would moving to type families help to clean up the undecidability?

Comment: Specifically, a definition like `foo x y = [tupSnd (x :. y), x]` that demands the instance `TupSnd (a :. c) a` will cause the type checker to loop.  (With `UndecidableInstances`, you'll get a  "reduction stack overflow" error.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable `UndecidableInstances`, it's a harmless extension.

Or, alternatively, you could switch to type families. The following code compiles (with no other extension beyond `TypeFamilies`). In the code below, I slightly changed your types so to avoid importing a bunch of modules. You should be able to easily adapt it back to your case.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class TupSnd a where
   type T a
   tupSnd :: a -> T a

instance TupSnd Bool where
   type T Bool = String
   tupSnd a = show a

instance (TupSnd a, TupSnd c) => TupSnd (a, c) where
   type T (a, c) = (T a, T c)
   tupSnd (a, c) = (tupSnd a, tupSnd c)
```

Personally, I find type families simpler to use than functional dependencies, so I prefer to use them whenever possible.